# bundle installするとgem install linecache19に失敗する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv, bundler

あるrailsアプリケーションのruby,RonRのバージョンアップをしようとしています。
まずrubyのバージョンをアップ（ruby 1.9.2p320⇒2.2.3）したところbundle installで失敗するようになり以下のようなエラーを出すようになりました。

```
[devel@CS-c014 3.3.x_version_up]$ rbenv exec bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 10.1.1
 :
 :
Installing linecache19 0.5.12 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151008-8095-rmksgw.rb extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39:in `create_makefile_with_core': uninitialized constant Ruby_core_source::Config (NameError)
        from extconf.rb:19:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linecache19-0.5.12 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/linecache19-0.5.12/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing linecache19 (0.5.12), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install linecache19 -v '0.5.12'` succeeds before bundling.
```

gem 'ruby-debug19'を使用しているのですがrubyバージョンあげると使えなくなるということでしょうか？エラーを解消する方法もしくは代替のgemがありましたら教えて頂けますでしょうか？

byebugを入れて上記問題は解決しました。その後再度bundle installしたところ次はmysql2でエラーになりました。Gemfile.lockで0.3.11を指定しているのですがこれを消すようにすればいいのでしょうか？それともbundle updateを使うようにした方がいいのでしょうか？

```
[devel@CS-c014 3.3.x_version_up]$ rbenv exec bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
 :
 :
Installing mysql2 0.3.11 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151009-7748-hhyv3.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling result.c
./client.h:11 から include されたファイル中,
                 ./mysql2_ext.h:39 から,
                 result.c:1 から:
/home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: 警告: #warning rubysig.h is obsolete
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:39,
                 from result.c:1:
./client.h:13: error: redefinition of typedef ‘rb_unblock_function_t’
/home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:897: note: previous declaration of ‘rb_unblock_function_t’ was here
./client.h:14: error: redefinition of typedef ‘rb_blocking_function_t’
/home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:898: note: previous declaration of ‘rb_blocking_function_t’ was here
./client.h: In function ‘rb_thread_blocking_region’:
./client.h:23: error: ‘TRAP_BEG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
./client.h:23: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
./client.h:23: error: for each function it appears in.)
./client.h:25: error: ‘TRAP_END’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [result.o] エラー 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/3.3.x_version_up/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/devel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/gemsets/3.3.x_version_up/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.11/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 2系ではruby-debug19ではなく、byebugを使うのがいいと思います。（というか、それしか使えないはずです）
Gemfileを書き換えて、再度bundle installしてみてください。

参考リンク

- [deivid-rodriguez/byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)
- [Ruby 2.0 向けのデバッガー byebugについて - Qiita](http://qiita.com/joker1007/items/f132db1b4a5e3f9278e9)

#### 追記

> その後再度bundle installしたところ次はmysql2でエラーになりました。

長い[Yak shaving](http://www.s-arcana.co.jp/tech/2011/10/yak-shaving.html)の始まりかもしれませんね。

確かに `bundle update mysql2` のようにすれば解決するかもしれません。（未確認）

mysql2の問題が解決しても、今後も繰り返し新しいエラーが発生するかもしれません。
その場合は `bundle update xxxx`のように、エラーになったgemをアップデートしていくとうまくいく可能性があります。
依存関係の問題でbundle updateできないと怒られた場合は、`bundle update foo bar` のように複数のgemを同時にアップデートしてください。

ただし、考えなしにgemをアップデートしていくと、互換性のない変更が取り込まれて今度はRailsが起動しなかったり、実行時エラーが発生したりするかもしれません。
gemのバージョン番号が大きく変わったときはそのあたりも注意してください。
（一番良いのはシステムの機能を網羅的に検証するテストコードが用意してあり、問題を自動的に検出できるようにしておくことです）

RubyやRailsのバージョンアップは何かと苦労を伴うものです。
プロジェクトの構成によって発生する問題と発生しない問題が無限にあるため、唯一の正解はありません。
エラーが起きたらネットの情報を調べたり、gemのコードを追いかけたりしながら、できるだけ自力で解決できるスキルを養っていくのが良いと思います。

Comment: byebugを使うようにして解決しました。その後上記のようにmysql2でエラーが出るようになりました。

Comment: 助言ありがとうございます。確かにbundle updateで解決したのですが今度は
Rails起動でエラーが出るようになりました。コード追いながら一つ一つ解決していきたいと思います。

`bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:302:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.1. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (LoadError)`